# How do I extend my partition on an ubuntu server

Tags: partitioning, fdisk

I'm running ubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS) under hyper-v and I've extended the hard drive (in hyper-v), but I now need to update ubuntu to use this space.

My current partitions looks as follows:

[image: Current Partitions]

A lot of the guides I've seen recommend deleting the second partition using fdisk and recreating it, but this appears to delete the sda5 partition and I'm thinking this is probably a very bad idea!

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After Deletion]

I'm at a bit of a loss as most searches suggest using a GUI tool which I don't have the luxury of!

I promise I have searched and searched

[EDIT]

After following the great answer below and using parted I now have FDisk showing

[image]

However I still don't have the space available
[image]

sudo pvs
  PV         VG               Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree 
  /dev/sda5  dar-docker-01-vg lvm2 a--  126.52g 52.00m

I'm guessing I need to do something again. I've tried using resize2fs but it's likely I'm not using it correctly!

[image]

[EDIT 2]

I needed to use

'pvresize /dev/sda5'

then use 'lvdisplay' to get the LV path

Then use 'lvextend -L+150G /dev/dar-docker-01-vg/root'

Finally 'resize2fs -p /dev/dar-docker-01-vg/root'

And after all that df -h shows the full space as available! YAY

Comment: Is it due to no Xorg? If so, at least Gparted from a Ubuntu live dvd can do the trick, as you have a monitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way for you is to :

1. Resize the extended partition `/dev/sda2` so that it takes all the space left after it ( end of partition at the end of the disk).
2. Resize the partition `/dev/sda5` inside `/dev/sda2` so that it ends at the end of `/dev/sda2`

To resize a partition without a GUI, I recommend you `parted` :

Go on a tty, launch `parted`.
You'll get a parted prompt, use `print` to display the current state of your disk.

Then to resize a partition: use `resizepart`
You'll be ask the number of the partition you want to resize ( to resize `/dev/sda2` enter 2 ,and then the end of the partition ( its new size ). For you the new size should be 'space on `/dev/sda2` + free space size' .

You can find how to resize a partition using parted :[here](http://www.tecmint.com/parted-command-to-create-resize-rescue-linux-disk-partitions/)

Comment: And of course deleting the `/dev/sda2` partition will delete `/dev/sda5` . The second partition is an extended one which means it can contain other partition, among it `/dev/sda5` .

Comment: Thanks - I've edited the question as I think it's nearly there but still not quite right!

Comment: I think you are using `resize2fs` correctly. I suspect that your problem comes from hyper-v, I don't know much about it, I'm not sure that I can help you further... Please let me know if you find how to fix that I am curious about it

Comment: I may have found a similar issue here : http://serverfault.com/questions/520103/extending-partition-on-linux-gparted-but-not-more-space-in-the-vm

Comment: Finally solved it - man what a pain in the backside! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same issue (but no LVM). Ubuntu on a VM in VirtualBox. Had to make the disk larger, which I first did in VirtualBox. Then needed to expand the partition and filesystem in Ubuntu.

Here is the disk after expanding the partition.

```
    Device            Boot               Start            End        Sectors        Size      Id Type
    /dev/sda1         *                   2048        1050623        1048576        512M       b W95 FAT32      
>>  /dev/sda2                          1052670      419430399      418377730      199,5G       5 Extended
    └─/dev/sda5                        1052672      419428351      418375680      199,5G      83 Linux
```

#### The solution

I had the luxury that I could use a GUI. I installed `gparted`. It took literally 30 seconds of work to expand the extended partition and then the logical partition inside it. That was the first time I used gparted and with no need for documentation. Great.

Before that I tried to do the same in `cfdisk` but sadly it could not do it and threw an error. I welcome suggestions for a command line tool that can do it and is self explanatory to use, just like the GUI. Cheers.